# Delphi DataSnap upload xml file in body

Tags: delphi, datasnap

in delphi 10 with the Datasnap component I am trying to declare a Post method that receives an XML file but I can't.

Does anybody know if Datasnap only can receive Json format type in the body?

(in contrary any example will be great)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide example code of what you were doing that didn't work for you.

Comment: I have tried to declare a post function as:
Function TServerMethods1.updatePostData(sFilename: string; sData: string): string;
I mean, a "update" method to say it is a POST and trying to say that in the body will come a "string" instead of a JSONObject, that in my case is a xml file. But everytime a try to execute the post I get {"error":"Message content is not a valid JSON value."} and my question was to know if only can be received a JSON structure in the body or if there are other structures to be received in the body, and how.
Thanks.

Comment: In [this technote](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/rest-servers-in-delphi-xe-using-datasnap.pdf) by Marcus Cantù, he mentions "While web services use either XML or JSON, Delphi REST servers default to the latter." There is no explanation on how to change it to accept the former. I am using 10.2 Tokyo and my DataSnap server is a service application that uses a TDataModule, so doesn't have a TWebModule that I can alter. Using PostMan, I can send the request but I get back "Message content is not a valid JSON value." unless I clear the body of the POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this with your datasnap WebModuleUnit and your custom ufileUploader unit like this :

1. In WebModuleUnit :

```pascal
    procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleDefaultAction(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
    begin
      if Request.InternalPathInfo.StartsWith('/UploadFile') then
        Response.Content := ufileUploader.UploadFile(Request)
      else if (Request.InternalPathInfo = '') or (Request.InternalPathInfo = '/')
      then
        Response.Content := ReverseString.Content
      else
        Response.SendRedirect(Request.InternalScriptName + '/');
    end;
```

2. in your ufileUploader unit :

```pascal
    unit ufileUploader;
    
    interface
    
    uses Web.HTTPApp;
    
    function UploadFile(ARequest: TWebRequest): string;
    
    implementation
    
    uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Web.ReqMulti;
    
    function UploadFile(ARequest: TWebRequest): string;
    const
      DestPath = 'c:\';
    var
      i: integer;
      LFileName: string;
      LStream: TMemoryStream;
    begin
      if not TMultipartContentParser.CanParse(ARequest) then
      begin
        Result := 'Cannot parse request';
        Exit;
      end;
      if ARequest.Files.Count < 1 then
      begin
        Result := 'No file sended';
        Exit;
      end;
      LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        // You have sended ARequest.Files.Count files
        for i := 0 to ARequest.Files.Count - 1 do
        begin
          LFileName := string(ARequest.Files.Items[i].FileName);
          LStream.Clear;
          // Read the sended file stream
          LStream.CopyFrom(ARequest.Files.Items[i].Stream,
            ARequest.Files.Items[i].Stream.Size);
          LStream.Position := 0;
          // Do what you want with the stream
          LStream.SaveToFile(DestPath + LFileName);
        end;
        Result := Format('%d files saved to %s ', [ARequest.Files.Count, DestPath]);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(LStream);
      end;
    end;
    
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you are hoping for, but I opened a case with Embarcadero for this exact problem and their response was:

> Hello
>
> My name is Steve Axtell. I am looking at this case.
>
> I am sorry but Datasnap does not support XML. It only supports JSON,
> hence the error message.
>
> Regards
>
> Steve Axtell Embarcadero Support ref:_00D30HwR._5005a28Y6yq:ref

The problem is in `Datasnap.DSService.TDSRESTService.ProcessParameters`:

```
// Look for more parameters in the body
if (Content <> nil) and (Length(Content) > 0) then
begin
  if LBody = nil then
  begin
    LBodyArray := nil;
    LBody := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Content, 0);
    LFreeBody := LBody;
    if LBody = nil then
    begin
      //ParamArray.Free;
      raise TDSServiceException.Create(SNoJSONValue);
    end;
    if (LBody is TJSONObject) and (TJSONObject(LBody).Count = 1) and
      (TJSONObject(LBody).Pairs[0].JSonString.Value = PARAMETERS_PAIR) and
      (TJSONObject(LBody).Pairs[0].JsonValue is TJSONArray) then
    begin
      LBodyArray := TJSONArray(TJSONObject(LBody).Pairs[0].JsonValue);
      LBodyArrayIndex := 0;
    end
  end;
end;
```

If the body is not in JSON, it fails to process the REST request, and I've not found a way to force DataSnap to not look in the body for additional parameters.

Note that in my case, I'm not using TComponent but TDataModule for the server methods.